# Chaining a command to the outcome of LetsEncrypt renewal

Tags: linux, scripting, letsencrypt

I would like to automate the running of this command (which is simple enough):

```
~/dehydrated/dehydrated --cron --domain www.mydomain.com --out . --challenge http-01
```

The problem is that I need to email my current host every time the certs renew so that they can implement the changes in the backend (very inefficient, I know, but there is no other way as only they have root access).

When I run the command above, it checks whether the current date is greater/less than 7 days from the certificate expiry date. When the time difference is greater it will return:

```
Processing www.mydomain.com
 + Checking domain name(s) of existing cert... unchanged.
 + Checking expire date of existing cert...
 + Valid till May  9 19:27:44 2018 GMT (Longer than 7 days). Skipping renew!
```

Whereas when the time difference is smaller it will renew the certs.

What I would like to do is make the script run every day. When the output is "Skipping renew" I'd like it to do nothing and close, and when the certificates **do** renew, I'd like to chain in another command (maybe with `&&`?) that sends an email to the hosts. I've already set this command up in python with a management command (`python manage.py email_hosts`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
~/dehydrated/dehydrated --cron --domain www.mydomain.com --out . --challenge http-01 | grep -q 'Skipping renew' || python manage.py email_hosts
```

### Explanation

- `|`: pipe the output of your initial command to the next command. This is assuming that it writes to standard out.
- `grep -q 'Skipping renew'`: search for `Skipping renew` in the output of the command before the pipe `|`. Act in "quiet" mode `-q`, i.e. don't actually show the match on the command line.
- `||` If the previous command fails (i.e. there is no match), then run the following command (i.e. email). This is essentially the opposite of `&&`. If the previous command matches something, then the email command won't run.

### Testing

You can also test the logic of the command flow with something like the following:

```
echo 'Skipping renew' | grep -q 'Skipping renew' || echo Mailing
echo 'Something else' | grep -q 'Skipping renew' || echo Mailing
```

Comment: Thanks @Sparhawk - works like a charm! Have a +1 and an accepted answer ;)